# toString, still giving me a weird output

Tags: java, tostring

Hey guys I just had a question about toString. On a previous test my professor had this overrided method for toString that was similar to this method which I'm testing:

```
public String toString()
{
String s="";
s+="units: " + units;
s+="\n";
s+="owner: " +owner;
return s;
}
```

This method is is inside the class Residential which inherits from a base class Construction. Anyways, this mirrors a problem I had on a test where I would try to do say:

```
Residential R1 = new Residential();
R1.toString();
```

I thought R1.toString(); would display, which I put on the test, but obviously it was marked wrong and it doesn't.

So now I'm going over the problem and how to correct it. I tried doing say:

```
System.out.println(R1.toString());
```

but it's still giving me some weird output like "Residential@5c538b31". Why does it not overriden?

edit: The whole residential class, I'm aware it's not overridden, now but it wasn't annoted with a @Override by the professor in his code either so I assumed it wasn't needed.

```
   public class Residential extends Construction {

    private int units;
    private String owner;

    Residential ()
    {
        super();
        units = 0;
        owner = "Unknown";
    }

    Residential (String n, int y, double a, int u, String o)
    {
        super (n,y,a);
        units = u;
        owner = o;
    }

    public int getUnits()
    {
        return units;
    }

    public void setUnits(int u)
    {
        units = u;
    }

    public String getOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String o)
    {
        owner = o;

    }

    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println("Name: " + getName() + " Year: " + getYear() + " Area: " + getArea() + " Number of Units: " + getUnits() + " Owner: " + getOwner());

    }

    public boolean isEqual (Residential r)
    {
        if (this.getName() == r.getName() && this.getYear() == r.getYear() && this.getArea() == r.getArea() && this.units == r.units && this.owner == r.owner)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        String s="";
        s += "the units is: " + units;
        s += "\n";
        s += "Owner: " + owner;

        return s;

    }
```

edit 2: Added construction class

```
 public class Construction {

private String buildername;
private int year;
private double area;


Construction()
{
    buildername = "Unknown";
    year = 0;
    area = -1;
}

Construction(String b, int y, double a)
{
    buildername = b;
    year = y;
    area = a;
}

//Mutators
public void setName(String n)
{
    buildername = n;

}

public void setYear(int y)
{
    year = y;
}

public void setArea (double a)
{
    area = a;
}

//Accessors

public String getName()
{
    return buildername;
}

public int getYear()
{
    return year;
}

public double getArea()
{
    return area;
}

public void display()
{
    System.out.println("Builder's Name: " + getName() + " Year: " + getYear() + " Area: " + getArea());     
}

public boolean isEqual(Construction c)
{
    if (this.buildername == c.buildername && this.year == c.year && this.area       == c.area)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the implementation of `R1`'s `toString()` method. The actual one, because this one isn't overridden.

Comment: post the whole Residential clas

Comment: If you want help debugging odd behavior in your code, posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) will help immensely.  If we can't *run* your code, we'll have a hard time helping you understand it.

Comment: The code looks good (I mean the toString method should work correctly). Are you sure you compiled the Residential class after you implemented the toString method?

Comment: Yeah I have. I've tested the simple display to test if say the default constructor is working, and it is.

Comment: @user2444400 post your Construction class

Comment: Added. I didn't have a toString in Construction, do I need one there?

Comment: @user2444400: the output you've posted, `"Residential@5c538b31"`, could not possibly come from the code you've posted. Re-compile and re-run your code and perhaps re-boot your IDE even.

Comment: I recompiled and rebooted and my output is now "Residential@6f9702b1". I'm using Eclipse, btw. Not sure if it matters.

Answer (score 4):

> but it's still giving me some weird output like "Residential@5c538b31". What am I doing wrong?

This means that your version of the Residential class does not correctly override the `toString()` method.

To fix this, you need to give your class a proper toString override. I would also give the method an `@Override` annotation to be sure that it's truly overriding the method.

You also state:

> On a previous test my professor had this overrided method for toString that was similar to this method which I'm testing...

... and yet you have not shown us the method that you're "testing". Perhaps you want to do this.

---

**Edit**
Regarding your posted code, that code is not what has produced the output that you've posted. Perhaps you need to refresh or restart your IDE, but the output could not possibly come from the posted code.

As an aside, your Residential `toString()` method should also call its parent class's `toString()` method in its method body, since the String returned should be part of Residential's String.

Comment: His actual toString looks like this: public String toString() {String s=""; s+="the length is " +l; s+="the width is" + w; s+="the area is arearect(); return s; }  This was in a Rectangle class, so I tried to do Rectangle R1 = new Rectangle(); R1.toString() <- Which was marked wrong with "This does not display!". So I tried to just test this out in this practice Residential class.

Comment: Yeah, but does yours?

Comment: @user2444400 post your Residential class so we could check

Comment: Residential R1 = new Residential();
System.out.println(R1.toString());   is what I'm using to try and output.

Comment: Okay, nevermind I found the problem. I'm an idiot. The Residential class was an edited one, outside of the package. So the toString method wasn't actually in the Residential class in the package. So the whole time I was calling the default object.toString method instead of an overrided Residential.toString method.